# Woocommerce Membership REST API check if user has a membership plan

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I ma developing a mobile app with a wordpress backend that was developed by someone else and the person is unreachable. I have the usual Woocomerce membership plans built on the backend. The website works perfectly fine. The issue is this

I checked the REST API endpoints through 'discovery' and found all the usual endpoints, but my issue is how will i test the if the user has a membership plan via REST API. I have already wasted a lot of time figuring out the solution.

- /wc/v3/memberships lists all the endpoints
- /wc/v3/memberships/plans/ lists all the plans

when i make a call to all these endpoints, it gives me all the users which have memberships.

My question is how would i know if the *current loggedin user* has purchased a membership, there is no such specific endpoint to it, plus the docs are not very specific. They are vaugue. Good enough for a beginner but not for a production level.

This is the url which i am referring to, which i got from the "official" Woocomerce Membership website
https://skyverge.github.io/woocommerce-memberships-rest-api-docs/#get-user-memberships

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  This question needs more details so that someone can actually help you.  You should consider reading [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this endpoint :
GET http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/memberships/members/
Just replace  with current user id. you can get current user id through this endpoint :
GET http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me